# C# How to use OADate to convert dates from database?

Tags: c#, date, charts, binding

I have a database table of dates and stock prices. I bind it to a WinForm Chart control according to the article. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489231(v=vs.110).aspx

I want to mark the highest data point as this article. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456612(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// Get relative coordinates of the data point
System.Drawing.PointF pos = System.Drawing.PointF.Empty;
pos.X = (float)cg.GetPositionFromAxis("ChartArea1", AxisName.X, i);
pos.Y = (float)cg.GetPositionFromAxis("ChartArea1", AxisName.Y, max);

// Convert relative coordinates to absolute coordinates.
os = cg.GetAbsolutePoint(pos);
```

Since the X-Axis is datetime value, I got pos.X = -99845. I think I should use OADate as the article. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456614(v=vs.110).aspx But I haven't figured out the way for the binding source.
[image]

Comment: You should show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find I should use the point's X value instead of its index i like in that tutorial example.

```
private void chart_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChartElement is Series && ((Series)e.ChartElement).Name == "Series3")
    {
        Series s = e.Chart.Series[0];
        ChartGraphics cg = e.ChartGraphics;
        double max = s.Points.FindMaxByValue().YValues[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Points.Count; i++)
        {
            if (s.Points[i].YValues[0] == max)
            {
                PointF pos = PointF.Empty;
                pos.X = (float)cg.GetPositionFromAxis("ChartArea1", AxisName.X, s.Points[i].XValue);
                pos.Y = (float)cg.GetPositionFromAxis("ChartArea1", AxisName.Y, max);

                pos = cg.GetAbsolutePoint(pos);

                for (int r = 10; r < 40; r+=10)
                {
                    cg.Graphics.DrawEllipse(
                        Pens.Red,
                        pos.X - r / 2,
                        pos.Y - r / 2,
                        r, r);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```